# Parsing Excel XML with PHP

Tags: php, xml, excel, parsing, csv

### INTRODUCTION

I'm using excel downloads as a way of users downloading a score sheet,
filling out scores and then re-uploading this score sheet into the
system.

Part of this requires the data in the database to be put into a CSV.
Then its opened on the client computer.

### PROBLEM

The problem I'm having is that the CSV does not allow me to use any
kind of formatting. This includes hiding cells, making text bold etc.

So parsing the data in and out of an excel format (xls) document would
make more sense... But from what I've heard and read, this would be
really difficult because of different excel versions etc etc.

### QUESTION

I heard that XML is a good way of parsing data into an excel format.
I wondered if anyone had any experience of this using php?

Is there a good script anyone has heard of?
Does anyone have any comments on different versions of excel opening
ir (or even, things like open office or lotus)
What do you think if my best step forward?

Thanks very much for your help!
Either reply or email me
tom at candid sky dot com

Comment: Nicely formatted question: +1 ...but is the data to be put into CSV for ease of insertion into the database, or is it extracted from the database as CSV so it can be opened again in Excel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try out [PHP](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/) [Excel](http://code.google.com/p/php-excel/) (not sure if both links are the same) and [PHP Excel Reader](http://code.google.com/p/php-excel-reader/).

Comment: These are great, but they seem a little heavy. Is there no small parser function that I could pull out?

Thanks for your help
Tom

Comment: Hi Tom, sorry those are the only Excel libraries for PHP that I know of, maybe you can try out COM objects, not sure if they fit your needs though.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there are, for example, Perl modules which would help with XML, but consider also that an HTML table: <tr>, <td>, <th> tags will be opened by Excel and at least *some* of the formatting will translate to Excel

you just have to name it ... `something.xls`

Comment: Plus you have to send headers so Excel open the document.

Comment: Apparently not - I generate the pseudo-xls file containing an HTML table, and nothing else; save it in a folder on a Windows file system, and Excel can open it as if it was a genuine Excel file.

Comment: Could I produce an excel spread sheet, save it as an xml file... then use this as a template to create a parser?

I'm just not sure how to extract the data from in between the fields (ie the parsing bit) - Any ideas? (I'm intermediate at php)

Comment: @pavium : you're right, I was thinking about force download. Sorry