# Download Excel Sheet and Parse for Web Use

Tags: javascript, php, html, excel

I am new to JavaScript and have done very basic web programming.  My background is much more in server-side development using C++ and Java.  I need to download an Excel spreadsheet for an external site on a regular basis (i.e. daily or weekly).  I then need to parse the Excel sheet to pull certain data fields for use on my site.  What is the easiest way to perform this functionality?

Comment: https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parsing Excel XML with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334646/parsing-excel-xml-with-php)

Answer (score -1):

I'm Nicolas, founder of Appizy (http://appizy.com). It's an online software that does mostly what you are asking for: converting spreadsheet into web content.

The cool thing is that the formulas are still running. They are converted in Javascript. You can check some examples here: http://appizy.com/toolbox

I hope this can help.

Best
Nicolas